# How can I load a text file in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, monogame

I created a new MonoGame iOS solution in Xamarin Studio. After that, I added a text file(File.txt) to my project.
But Xamarin Studio is not loading the text file when I run the project in the iPhone simulator. I get this error message in the following line:

```
System.IO.Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(filename);
```

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/Users/Name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1B232780-3BD1-4AE9-8475-100219150CEF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9631F7D3-CF8C-448A-989B-974E984600D7/Loadtextfile.app/File.txt".

Why is Xamarin Studio not finding the file? I added the text file to my solution in Xamarin Studio and my solution is saved on my Desktop.

How can I load the text file?

And here the complete code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Loadtextfile
{
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private const string filename = "File.txt";
    string[] strs;
    string tmpLine;

    public void LoadFile()
    {
        System.IO.Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(filename);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                strs = line.Split(';');
                //...
            }
        }
    }

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {           
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        LoadFile();
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the file and set the `Build Action` to "Content"